# Getting Null response From Async task With Response code 200 which means Success

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

When I Debug my code get Response code 200 which means success. Then also I'm getting null response.

Following is my AsyncTask Class:

```
 private class AsyncAddfriend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://ishook.com/users/friends/send_friend_request_json/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("sessionId", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("UserId", params[1])
                    .appendQueryParameter("friendId", params[2]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return(result.toString());


            }else{

                return("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }}
```

---

I have Tested My API in postman its Working with response code 200 and giving Response in json format but in my code its not working .

Hope you will understand my problem.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: what is the value of `response_code` during execution?

Comment: getting responcse_code 200

Comment: so it enters the if-clause right?

Comment: yes it enters in if-clause.

Comment: what is then the value o `String line;`? (sorry for this but it is the only way I can debug it)

Comment: getting null value of line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160094/discussion-between-arlo-shie-and-joao86).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably from this line:

```
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

You need to use:

```
String query = builder.build().toString();
```

This is because getEncodedQuery() is only returning the query, from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getEncodedQuery()):

> String getEncodedQuery ()
>
> Gets the encoded query component from this URI. The query comes after the query separator ('?') and before the fragment separator ('#'). This method would return "q=android" for "http://www.google.com/search?q=android".

---

**UPDATED**

You're building the query after opening the connection, hence you having the error.

You need to build the url with the query first:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://ishook.com/users/friends/send_friend_request_json/")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("sessionId", params[0])
        .appendQueryParameter("UserId", params[1])
        .appendQueryParameter("friendId", params[2]);
        .build();

 URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

 conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
 conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setDoInput(true);
 conn.setDoOutput(true);

 conn.connect();
```

Note: I haven't test the code. So, don't expected it working automagically.

Comment: sir as you said try String query = builder.build().toString(); in result getting Disallowed Key Characters.

Comment: Try adding  `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: What is the value of query from `String query = builder.build().toString();`? You need to debug the code step by step.

Comment: the value query ?sessionId=94a06a4eef1a34b555e4bacf911618fe&UserId=22960&friendId=23286

Comment: Ohh.. looks like you forgot to build the url with the query first then open the connection.

Comment: @arloshie: Last attempt, change your below the comment `//read data send from server` with:                 `InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input), "UTF-8");`

Comment: sorry but its not valid syntax sir

Comment: Sir can we have discussion on Team Viwer

Comment: I can't do that currently. Still working in the office right now. I will be free at 2 hours from now. I'll try to arrange my time for you.

Comment: OK Thank you sir !

Comment: sir are you free now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160209/discussion-between----and-arlo-shie).

Comment: Sir when Will you free today?

Comment: sir  are you free now ?